# Rails: find text fragment within a ActiveSupport:SafeBuffer element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

I'm using Simple Navigation in my rails app, where I have a render_navigation function, with returns a ActiveSupport:SafeBuffer. As I want to delete the selected tag I tried to iterated through this SafeBuffer, but Im not sure how to do this...

```
    <%= render_navigation(:level => 4).each do |level|
        if !level.to_s.gsub("selected").nil?
           level
        end
    end %>
```

This returns the error:

> undefined method `to_str' for #`<`Enumerable::Enumerator:0x103be1e60>

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

When using `gsub`, you need to supply two fields. The string you're selecting, and what you want to substitute it with. In your case, you're just looking to see if a string exists I presume.

I would recommend `match`.

```
if !level.to_s.match(/selected/).nil?
```

Source: http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#M001538